# Fraction of \textwidth as image width

Tags: graphics, width

I would like to specify the width of an image as a fraction of a predefined length, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[width=1/3*\textwidth]{}
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \includegraphics[width=1/3*\textwidth]{}
```

Comment: 1/3~0.33333, so use `0.33333\textwidth`.

Comment: You can use `\dimexpr<calculation>\relax` while invoking the `calc` package.

Comment: You can also read on how to make `\newlength` here in TeX.SX

Comment: I just found the calc package. {\textwidth/\real{3}} works for me. I want to use a fraction, since I have n subfigures next to each other and it's easier to read if each width is \textwidth/n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with `lualatex`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\w{\directlua{tex.sprint(1/3)}}

This is my graph, it has width of \w and it looks very nice

\includegraphics[width=\w\textwidth]{}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

Informally, length calculation are done using *factor multiplication* as there is no *division* notation. Since any division can be represented as some multiplication, this shouldn't be a problem. So, `.5\textwidth` refers to half (1/2) of `\textwidth`, while `2\wd0` refers to twice the `w`i`d`th of box `0`. In your case it suffices to use

```
\includegraphics[width=0.3333\textwidth]{<img>}
```

You can perform all kinds of calculations using [`calc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) or even LaTeX3:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\textwidth}

\verb|\mylen|: \the\mylen

\setlength{\mylen}{\calc{1/3}\textwidth}
\verb|1/3\mylen|: \the\mylen

\end{document}
```

The LaTeX3 syntax above makes `\calc` an `new` `c`ontrol `s`equence (or macro) that is `eq`uivalent to `\fp_eval:n` - a `fl`oating `p`oint function that `eval`uates it's argument using the regular programming arithmetic (like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `^`, ...) taking a single argument.

Comment: You should shed some light into the LaTeX3 syntax for the other users who might not know the construct of LaTeX3 code.

Comment: thank you for this lightening of the LATEX3 syntax, it's scary at first.